# Why do most textbooks not explicitly talk about tricks in doing proofs?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, education

When trying to prove a proposition we usually either try to prove by the result of some related theorems, or try some "tricks" that often work for "similar" types of problems. Textbooks in mathematics are often structured by definitions and theorems (and lemmas, etc.), and sometimes some explanation of the intuition behind theorems, but usually authors won't explicitly mention certain techniques/tricks that they used in the proof, and it takes time to understand what they did in certain parts of the proof. I'm wondering why didn't anyone (at least to my knowledge) make a systematic listing of such strategies/techniques/tricks, as they are also important to mathematics.

Also has there been any examples where something that used to be an informal trick later becomes a formalized theorem once we know exactly what is the condition to apply the trick? Do all tricks have the potential of becoming theorems?

Posting in real analysis because I don't really know where I should post, and this is the field where such tricks seem most commonly used.

Comment: Hi wella. Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I think your question would be clearer if you provided an example of the kind of trick you are talking about.

Comment: This is a stylistic choice of the author. Some authors talk about it, some don't. For example, Terrence Tao's measure theory text has a short section on "tricks." Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis does not have any discussion of tricks. Strichartz' Way of Analysis has extensive discussion of the techniques used in every proof. Other texts are somewhere in between.

Comment: There is a quote from Gauss, roughly like: "the architect shows the finished building, not the scaffolding" or something. Mathematicians tend to prefer to show polished proofs for various reasons (if you're feeling kind, the reason is aesthetic). I agree textbooks should discuss motivations more so than they tend to

Comment: You may be interested by: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/tricks-wiki-give-yourself-an-epsilon-of-room/, https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/

Comment: Without an example or two, we won't know what you are referring to.

Comment: The authors probably don’t want the book to be bloated. But they also specify the level of knowledge expected from the readers. On the other hand, there are books such as “Problem Solving Strategies” by Arthur Engel that are entirely dedicated to discuss “tricks” or more elegantly, strategies.